# Calendar overlaps

Tags: html, css, calendar

As you can see below, the calendar I have is overlapping with the content below.

I currently using the following css for the calendar and I am not sure what is going on:

```
    @media (max-width:767px){
    .upcoming-events-image { 
     max-width: 180px;
     max-height: 180px;
     width:95%;
    }
    .hidden-xs{
        display:inline !important;
    }
    .fc-scroller{
        overflow: visible !important;
        display:inline-block !important;
     }
}
```

[image: As you, the calendar is overlapping and not sure why]

Any  help would be appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE

```
    <cffunction name="FullCalendar">

    <cfscript>

        var calendarid = $.getbean('content').loadby(title='Regal Events').getcontentid();


    </cfscript>
    <cfsavecontent variable="local.str">
        <cfoutput>           

                 <div id="UpcomingCal" class="calendarResize">
                 </div>
         <script>

         mura.loader()
            .loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css",{media:'all'})
            <!---.loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-custom.css",{media:'all'})--->
            .loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css",{media:'print'})
            .loadjs(
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js",
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js",
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/gcal.js",
                function(){
                     $('##UpcomingCal').fullCalendar({
                         weekMode: 'variable',
                         eventSources: [
                            {
                                url: '#variables.$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/proxy.cfc?calendarid=#esapiEncode("javascript",CalendarID)#'
                                , type: 'POST'
                                , data: {
                                    method: 'getFullCalendarItems'
                                    , calendarid: '#esapiEncode("javascript",CalendarID)#'
                                    , siteid: '#variables.$.content('siteid')#'
                                    , categoryid: '#esapiEncode('javascript',variables.$.event('categoryid'))#'
                                    , tag: '#esapiEncode('javascript',variables.$.event('tag'))#'

                                }
                                <!---, color: '#this.calendarcolors[colorIndex].background#'
                                , textColor: '#this.calendarcolors[colorIndex].text#'--->
                                , error: function() {
                                    $('##mura-calendar-error').show();
                                }
                            },
                        ]
                    });
                }
               )
         </script>

        </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn local.str />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Is the calendar a dropdown?

Comment: Could you please share the code, or create a fiddle that we can play with ?

Comment: No it is not a drop down @EliTownsend

Comment: @melwynpawar I am using fullcalendar js and I will upload the code so you can see. Also I am using coldfusion and Mura and I am new two both

Comment: @RobertoFlores can you try adding the following into our css i was just checking full calendar js

.fc-scroller.fc-day-grid-container {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

Comment: @melwynpawar Yes it has that but I would like it not to have a scroll bar on the side. I would like it to show the full calendar

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to the CSS and it should do it

```
.fc-scroller.fc-day-grid-container {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: I will try and see if that works but I feel I have tried this before. Thank You

Comment: let me know if it doesn't will again look into it, but I think the specificity should do the job :)

Comment: Melywyn pawar:  Thank You, I hope it does. I have one more question: How would I hide events that do not belong to the current month. I know you would use eventRender but everytime I do, the calendar would disappear. Any help would be appreciated